# SQL file import where text contains comma (,)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, import

I'm trying to import a csv file into a MySQL database.
The problem is thet some of the text is wrapped with " " and contains comma.

Comma is also the separator for the cells, so when the text contains comma it split up into a new cell.

The file is looking like this:

```
id,first name,last name,comment
"152,45,3",James,Bond,"Hi, this is my comment."
"152,46,3",Donald,Duck,Comment whitout caracters
"152,47,4",Peter,Peterson,"Hi! Cool, this is my comment"
```

Anyone that have a solution for this?

I have tried this to import it:

```
sed '/id/d' "Data.csv" > /tmp/data.csv
```

SQL:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE "/tmp/data.scv"
REPLACE INTO TABLE database.table
COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ','
```

Comment: Your data source is faulty.  James Bond should appear quoted/escaped, e.g. as `"James,Bond"`.

Comment: Hi Tim, I know the data file is not good. But this is how I get it from another system that I have no control over.

Comment: Then you may need to write a parser to process it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a workaround by remove commas inside " ".

```
perl -pe 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9.\s"](?!(?:"[^"]*"|[^"])*$)//g' Data.csv > /tmp/data.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

**You just need to add OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"':**

LOAD DATA INFILE "/tmp/data.scv"
REPLACE INTO TABLE database.table
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ','

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ','' at line 1